# Create inlineImages JSON dynamically for MailApp.sendMail

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I'm making a Google Apps Script that sends an email based on a template made in a Google Doc file. The Google Doc file looks like:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi
>   pulvinar odio ac velit maximus, et dapibus justo porttitor. Morbi
>   libero quam, hendrerit ut ex vulputate, viverra pellentesque leo.
>   Aenean sodales vulputate tellus rutrum lobortis.
>
> image1
>
> Morbi sed molestie lectus, in mattis magna. Maecenas imperdiet quis
>   sem nec eleifend. Ut at nulla ornare, egestas nibh nec, sodales risus.
>   Duis risus augue, dictum in molestie vitae, vestibulum eu sapien.
>
> image2
>
> Phasellus nulla elit, ornare at leo vitae, pellentesque scelerisque
>   dui. Phasellus commodo lectus eu nisl ullamcorper ullamcorper. Sed
>   velit tellus, tempor in efficitur ac, semper vel nunc.

First, I retrieve the text from the Google Doc:

```
var emailText = DocumentApp.openById(emailtextID).getBody().getText();
```

Next, the `image#` in the template text is replaced to make the cid's:

```
var startImageNumber = 1;
  while(emailText.indexOf("image" + startImageNumber) !=-1){
    emailTextHtml = emailText.replace("image" + startImageNumber, "<br> <img src='cid:image" + startImageNumber + "'> <br>");
    startImageNumber++;
}
```

Now the template is ready to be used in the mail. However, first the image blobs must be retrieved and the JSON for the cid's must be made. The images are png files and they are located in the same folder in Google Drive as the Google Doc is located. The imageBlobs JSON holds the blobs from the images retrieved and the blobJSON is basically a JSON that links the cid's to the imageBlob variables in the imageBlobs JSON.

```
var imageBlobs = {};
var blobJSON = {};
for(i = 0; i < startImageNumber - 1; i++){
    try{
      imageBlobs["imageBlob" + (i+1)] = DriveApp.getFilesByName("image" + (i+1) + ".PNG").next().getBlob().setName("imageBlobs.imageBlob" + (i+1));
      blobJSON["image" + (i+1)] = "imageBlobs.imageBlob" + (i+1);
    }
    catch(e){
      Logger.log("Error: " + e);
    }
}
```

Finally, once the blobs have been retrieved, I'd like to send the mail. When I do the following (i.e. using the dynamically created JSON with the blobs), I get an error:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({to: "test@test.com",subject: "Testsubject",
                     htmlBody: emailTextHtml, inlineImages: blobJSON});
```

The error message says:

> Invalid argument: attachments (line ..., file "")

What am I doing wrong here? Why do I get an error message saying that I'm missing the attachments while I'm trying to use inlineImages only?

Any help is much appreciated!

Robin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the whole code and I try to suggest you have to owerride `inlineImages` value like this:

```
inlineImages: Object.keys(blobJSON).reduce(function(pV, cV, i) {
  pV[cV] = eval(blobJSON[cV]);
  return pV;
},{})
```

It works for me fine. There is an [example](https://script.google.com/d/1puD_7HXOopWUZ0uzD__t7aLO3x5RQtsTHqmO_M6aOtYGTB6QcwMuxhSE/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am well aware of the KISS principle, though the variable names might have been chosen unfortunately here, I have to agree on that. Though the correction you present, is not a problem here. The final JSON (the blobJSON used in the inlineImages for Mailapp.sendMail()) should have the structure: {image1: imageBlob1}. Since this would require me to make dynamic variables (e.g. imageBlob# variables), I decided to put the blobs in a JSON too (hence, imageBlobs.imageBlob#). That's what I'm referring to in the blobJSON, which results in {image1: imageBlobs.imageBlob1}.

Comment: So the point here is, that I'm unable to make variables dynamically. I've updated the original post to clarify the difference between the two JSONs.

Comment: @RobinTrietsch ok, i've rewriten the answer

Comment: Thank you very much, I've been struggling with this for hours! Could you explain me how it works? I do get the 'eval' part, but the rest not.

Comment: Your `blobJSON` contains strings. The strings represent names of variables from the namespace. The code just iterates each `blobJSON` key, evaluates values and push its to a new object. The code returns this object.